# R Blogdown Hugo academic theme not rendering site

Tags: r, hugo, blogdown, hugo-shortcode

I am trying to create a website using R Blogdown Hugo-Academic theme. Typically, I would create a website by running the following commands:

```
blogdown::new_site(theme = 'gcushen/hugo-academic')
blogdown::serve_site()
```

But I am getting an error

```
failed to extract shortcode: template for shortcode "alert" not found
```

I found a related github issue [here](https://github.com/wowchemy/wowchemy-hugo-modules/issues/1034):

But it seems like `gcushen/hugo-academic` is shifting to `wowchemy`

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem, and resolved it by editing my config.toml file:

Check that your theme is set correctly (mine was):

```
# Name of Academic theme folder in `themes/`.
theme = "wowchemy-hugo-modules"
```

Append to the end:

```
[module]
  [[module.imports]]
    path = "wowchemy-hugo-modules/wowchemy"
```

as per https://wowchemy.com/docs/install-locally/

Then `stop_server()` and `serve_site()` as usual.

Comment: this solves the issue (had the same problem). Is this also the reason for the kickstart error when trying to run blogdown::new_site(theme = 'gcushen/hugo-academic')?

Comment: The development version of **blogdown** should work now: `remotes::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')`. I'll appreciate it if you could help test it!